# subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector, i get this error message when i try to execute this kernel code

Tags: python, c, opencl, pyopencl

```
xx_np = np.random.rand(16500).astype(np.float32)
u_np = np.random.rand(16500).astype(np.float32)
vector_np = np.random.rand(16500).astype(np.float32)
temp_np = np.random.rand(16500).astype(np.float32)
ctx= cl.Context([device])  #context
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx) #commandqueue

mf = cl.mem_flags #memoryflags

xx_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=xx_np)

u_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=u_np)

vector_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=vector_np)

temp_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=temp_np)

q00=q0

prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
__kernel void dota( __global float *xx, __global float *u, __global float *vector, __global float *temp, __global float *res, float q00, float s,float i)

{

    int index = get_global_id(0);

    int qindex= get_global_id(0);

    res[index] = xx[index]*u[index-1];

    res[index] = res[index]*u[index-1];

    xx[index]= xx[index]-res[index];

    float a=   pow(pow(xx[index],2)+pow(xx[index+1],2),0.5);

    float b=   pow(pow(vector[index],2)+pow(vector[index+1],2),0.5);

    if(b==0)

    {   i=vector[qindex]+q00;

        b=pow(pow(i,2)+pow(i,2),0.5);

    }       

    s=100*(a/b);

    s[index]=s;

    temp[index]=s[index];

}

""").build()

res_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, temp_np.nbytes)

prg.dota(queue, temp_np.shape, None, temp_g, xx_g,res_g)

res_np = np.empty_like(temp_np)

cl.enqueue_copy(queue, res_np, res_g)

print res_np
```

subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector, I get this error message when I try to execute this kernel code.

I am new to opencl and kernel codes so cant figure out why am i getting this error message. because I have taken the `global_id(0)` and then using its size as my index. It should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

`s` is a float variable, so `s[index]=s;` will raise the error

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you have defined

- `s` as  `..., float s, ...`
- `index` as `int index`

where neither is an array or pointer. But later, you write

```
 s[index]=s;
```

As per `C11`, chapter §6.5.2.1, array subscripting Constraints,

> One of the expressions shall have type *‘‘pointer to complete object type’’*, the other
>   expression shall have integer type.

which is violated, hence you see the error.

Comment: also sqrt(x * x + y * y) could be 50 times faster than pow(pow pow) for some systems